# Change state when back to app

Tags: android, android-intent, back

For example, I have one activity that contains one edittext and button.I write something on it then click button.And button goes to another app this is my code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message.getText().toString());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Then after sharing, how can I make to go to another activity(or fragment) when I back to my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then override `onActivityResult` inside your Activity class to get notify when the user come back to your app

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            // do stuffs here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, but how can I make it in fragment(activity contains 2 fragment)

Comment: @KuanyshLes you can override onActivityResult inside your fragment, but you should call startActivityForResult inside your fragment, is that solve your problem or its something else?

Comment: The problem is my 2 fragments in one activity.When I tried to do it immediately calls startActivityForResult(). I mean it calls this method before "not finishing sending share intent"